# Apache Airflow - customize logging format

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to customize the format that Airflow uses for logging?

I tried adding a LOG_FORMAT variable in $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg, but it doesn't seem to take effect

```
LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s logLevel=%(levelname)s logger=%(name)s - %(message)s"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the settings.py file in the airflow package to change the log format

- Update **settings.py** (after LOGGING_LEVEL add below line):

  LOG_FORMAT = os.path.expanduser(conf.get('core', 'LOG_FORMAT'))
- Update **airflow.cfg** configuration file:
  Add line under [core]:

  LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s logLevel=%(levelname)s logger=%(name)s - %(message)s"
- Restart **webserver** and **scheduler** services

  Try the approach as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173554/apache-airflow-control-over-logging-disable-adjust-logging-level) to change logging level

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of settings.py. If you look at it, there is a comment next to LOG_FORMAT that reads "# can't move this to conf due to ConfigParser interpolation". So I ended up just modifying those strings in settings.py

Comment: you might receive a ConfigParser.InterpolationMissingOptionError because with the '%' operator the config thinks you are referencing to a variable in the config. like @csab said it might be better to modify the string in the settings.py