# Apache Airflow: Control over logging [Disable/Adjust logging level]

Tags: python, airflow

I am using Airflow 1.7.1.3 installed using pip

I would like to limit the logging to ERROR level for the workflow being executed by the scheduler. Could not find anything beyond setting log files location in the settings.py file.

Also the online resources led me to this google group discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/EjwTpsd9Yi4) but not much info here as well

**Any idea how to control logging in Airflow?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logging functionality and its configuration will be changed in version 1.9 with this [commit](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/3c3a65a3fe2edbd7eee1d736735194a1ca14962a)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Marking this as accepted answer as upgrading airflow is a better solution

Answer (score 16):

I tried below work around and it seems to be working to set `LOGGING_LEVEL` outside of `settings.py`:

- Update `settings.py`:

  - Remove or comment line:
    `LOGGING_LEVEL = logging.INFO`
  - Add line:
    `LOGGING_LEVEL = os.path.expanduser(conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL'))`
- Update `airflow.cfg` configuration file:

  - Add line under `[core]`:
    `logging_level = WARN`
  - Restart `webserver` and `scheduler` services
- Use environment vaiable `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL=WARN`.

See [the official docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/set-config.html) for details.

Comment: LOGGING_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL') why are you expanding the ~ ? This setting is not a path.

Comment: Note that `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL` has been deprecated in favour of `AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL` since 2.0.0:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#logging-level-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

As @Dimo Boyadzhiev pointed the change, Adding the more info path for documentaion.

```
File - $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg

# Logging level
logging_level = INFO
fab_logging_level = WARN
```

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I am aware of is changing `LOGGING_LEVEL` in `settings.py` file. Default level is set to `INFO`.

```
AIRFLOW_HOME = os.path.expanduser(conf.get('core', 'AIRFLOW_HOME'))
SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN') 
LOGGING_LEVEL = logging.INFO
DAGS_FOLDER = os.path.expanduser(conf.get('core', 'DAGS_FOLDER'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-compose.yaml

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    #the other parameters 
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL: DEBUG #add
```