# Airflow - Bach command failed

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to execute following airflow dag file. but getting following error.

```
import json
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

args = {
   'owner': 'test',
   'start_date': days_ago(2),
   'depends_on_past': False,
}

dag = DAG(
   dag_id='test',
   default_args=args,
   schedule_interval='0 5 * * *',
   tags=['test']
)

start_test = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start_test',
    dag=dag,
)

end_test = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end_test',
    dag=dag,
)

load_complete = DummyOperator(
    task_id='load_complete',
    dag=dag,
)

execution_date = datetime.now()
def check_monthstart_trigger(execution_date, **kwargs):
   return execution_date.day() == 1

for i in json.loads(open('/home/test_123/list_of_files.json', 'r').read())['tables'].keys():
    extract_phase = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'extract_' + str(i),
    bash_command = 'python3 /home/python/extract_code.py -t {}'.format(i),
    dag = dag,
    )
    create_phase = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'modify_' + str(i),
    bash_command = 'python3 /home/python/table_create.py -t {}'.format(i),
    dag = dag,
    )
    load_phase = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'load_' + str(i),
    bash_command = 'python3 /home/python/load_test.py -t {}'.format(i),
    dag = dag,
    )
start_test >> extract_phase >> create_phase >> load_phase >> load_complete >> end_test
```

This is the error what i am getting

[image]

i have tried this solution also ([Error calling BashOperator: Bash command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293576/error-calling-bashoperator-bash-command-failed)) but didn't work. Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: As indicated by stacktrace, [line 165](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2d4e44c04e78adf887cf7ebe3decfca64e7c9158/airflow/operators/bash.py#L165) says that your bash-command is returning non-zero exit code. As per [line 144](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2d4e44c04e78adf887cf7ebe3decfca64e7c9158/airflow/operators/bash.py#L144) you should also see the exact command Airflow is triggering. If not, check that your [log-level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42188333/3679900) is correctly configured

Comment: you have extra "}}" at the end of `bash_command` for extract_ and load_

Comment: Hi @Emma sirry that's my mistake.those brackets are not there